# CVE-2016-2107 Apache

Tags: apache-httpd, ssl

I have 2 production servers both with Ubuntu 14 and `OpenSSL 1.0.1f` 6 Jan 2014 and when I test both servers against ssllabs only one of them is vulnerable to CVE-2016-2107. The only difference I could find is, the not vulnerable server have the following Apache version :

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jul 15 2016 15:34:04
```

whereas the vulnerable one has the following:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jan 14 2016 17:45:23
```

So my question is: how do I secure the server? Do I rebuild the Apache?

Answer (score 1):

The server running Apache built in January 2016 isn't up-to-date; you need to apply the available security fixes:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This will upgrade [the apache2 package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2) to version 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.13 (July 2016), and probably lots of other packages with security fixes.